# Naiant X-X omni miniature mics

Tags: rode, omni, dpa

investigating for a pair of miniature omnis I came across the Naiant X-X.
Did somebody ever had a chance to test or even compare them against the much more expensive Rode Lavalier or DPA 4060?

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect that the Naiant microphones can perform as well as microphones that cost 10x to 50x more $$$.  You can expect that the Naiant microphones will have somewhat more self-noise, perhaps higher distortion and a frequency response not quite as wide or flat.

Will you actually HEAR these differences in the final mix? It depends on what you are recording and how you are processing it. There are plenty of situations where you won't hear a significant difference.

If you had the budget to buy DPA (or even Rode) then why are you looking at the Naiant?  They all have their place in the marketplace. You can buy a Toyota or you can buy a Lamborghini. The Toyota will get you where you are going just as well as the Lamborghini.

Answer (score 0):

hi see if you could source a second hand pair mkh-20 sennheisor ..great true ,larger than life can be used outdoor.while the dpas do sound good its a matter of reliability in varied temperatures and moisture levels.if can not afford look for the cheapest omnis that can handle the same conditions.matched pair preferable otherwise match it by listening if you get a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your reason to use a mic like this will depend entirely on application and budget. Price of any audio equipment will generally rise with brand exposure and knowledge. However, it is certainly possible that cheaper equipment will be just as useful - but it depends entirely on the application.

for instance, you wouldn't use a lavalier such as this for drama where you need to hide a microphone. It is way too big for hidden use, and so consequently can't be compared to the Rode Lavalier or the DPA dScreet series.

Work out what falls within your budget and then get the best microphone you can for the budget you have available to you that will fit the application you have in mind.